# Bash: Renaming file with date and Version number

Tags: bash

I keep my files version controlled, with filenames such as "2024-02-12 Work Presentation V.1". I'm trying to get a bash script running that automatically versions this (on triggering the script), so the date is updated to the current one, and the Version number is updated. However, if a filename already exists, the version is meant to increment, instead of overwriting a file.

I originally had a bunch of `if` and `elif` statements, but I'm trying to get it to work with `case` now. I'm struggling with updating the date.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
current_date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')

# Function to check if a file exists
file_exists() {
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        return 0  # File exists
    else
        return 1  # File does not exist
    fi
}

# Function to increment the version number
increment_version() {
    local version_number="$1"
    local incremented_version=$((version_number + 1))
    echo "$incremented_version"
}

# Check if the filename starts with a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD
case "$filename" in
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\ *V.[0-9]*)
        echo "Filename starts with a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD."
        echo "Filename contains the current date followed by Versionnumber (V.1, V.2, etc.)."
        # Extract the version number from the filename
        version_number=$(echo "$filename" | grep -oP 'V\.\K\d+')
        
        # Check if a file with the same version number exists
        while file_exists "$filename"; do
            echo "File with version $version_number already exists."
            # Increment the version number
            version_number=$(increment_version "$version_number")
            # Modify the filename with the incremented version number
            filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed "s/V\.[0-9]*/V.$version_number/")
        done

        echo "Creating new file with version $version_number."
        # Copy the original file to the new filename
                        # Add the current date to the start of the filename
            new_filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/^.\{11\}//')
 
            new_filename_with_date="${current_date} ${new_filename}"
                    
        cp "$1" "$filename"
        echo "$new_filename_with_date"
 
        ;;
   *) [OTHER CASES]
```

It correctly `echoes` the `new_filename_with_date`, however if I try putting that as the goal of the copying, it now no longer increments the versions, which I don't understand.

The other cases will include things like if the filename has a date but no version number and vice versa.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT: I've added a closer solution as an answer.

Comment: It's a long question, with relatively long script. Can you narrow the question - what are the line(s) that you need help. What is the input (variable values), and expected output.
Even better: provide sample input and output for the whole task. You will get better answers.

Comment: Export your function. `export -f function_name`

Comment: Not to sidetrack your entire question, but why don't you just use an existing version control system, like Git? Granted, commands like `git diff` won't be terribly useful for binary files, but it will be far more flexible than having to wade through a directory of similarly named files. (And the commit messages can contain important information like *why* `2024-02-17 Work Presentation V.3` is different from `2024-02-16 WorkPresentation V.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on your requirements, this script should to do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

originalFilename="$1"
#
# This function returns the highest version number for the given baseName and extension.
latestVer () {
  local baseName="$1"
  local fileExt="$2"

  maxVer=$(ls -1 | egrep -e "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] ${baseName} V.[0-9]*${fileExt}" | sed -ne 's/.* V\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' | sort -n | tail -1)
  if [ -z "$maxVer" ]; then
    echo 0
  else
    echo $maxVer
  fi
}

if [ ! -e "$originalFilename" ]; then
  echo "Error, can't access '$originalFilename'." 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
#
# First deconstruct the filename to get the parts.
baseName="$1"
#
# Check to see if the file already has the date in front.
fileDate=$(echo "$baseName" | sed -ne 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\) .*/\1/p')
#
# If the filename already has the date, strip it off.
if [ ! -z "$fileDate" ]; then
  baseName=$(echo "$baseName" | sed -ne 's/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] \(.*\)/\1/p')
fi
#
# Check to see if it has an extension:
#   First check if the only extension is the version number.
fileExt=""
fileVer=$(echo "$baseName" | sed -ne 's/.*V\.\([0-9]*\)$/\1/p')
if [ -z "$fileVer" ]; then
  fileExt=$(echo "$baseName" | sed -ne 's/.*\(\..*\)$/\1/p')
fi
#
# If it has an extension, strip it off
if [ ! -z "$fileExt" ]; then
  baseName=$(echo "$baseName" | sed -ne 's/\(.*\)\..*$/\1/p')
fi
#
# Check to see if the version number already exist.
fileVer=$(echo "$baseName" | sed -ne 's/.* V\.\([0-9]*\)$/\1/p')
#
# If it has a version number, strip it off
if [ ! -z "$fileVer" ]; then
  baseName=$(echo "$baseName" | sed -ne 's/\(.*\) V\.[0-9]*$/\1/p')
fi

targetFileVer=$(latestVer "$baseName" "$fileExt")
let targetFileVer+=1
#
# Get the current date.
curDate=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
#
# If the original filename didn't have a fileDate or a fileVer then this must be the
# first time of it being put into this naming convention. So, move the file to the new
# naming convention, and the next step will copy a new version.
if [ -z "$fileDate" -o -z "$fileVer" ]; then
  #
  # Move the file, while perserving any versioning components that are already there.
  moveFilename="${fileDate:-$curDate} $baseName V.${fileVer:-$targetFileVer}${fileExt}"
  mv "$originalFilename" "$moveFilename"
  originalFilename="$moveFilename"
  targetFileVer=$(latestVer "$baseName" "$fileExt")
  let targetFileVer+=1
fi
#
# The new filename should be "<currentDate> <filename> V.<versionNumber>"
targetFilename="$curDate $baseName V.$targetFileVer${fileExt}"
while [ -e "$targetFilename" ]; do
  let targetFileVer+=1
  targetFilename="$curDate $baseName V.$targetFileVer${fileExt}"
done

cp "$originalFilename" "$targetFilename"
```

Test case 1:
My goal is to check the filename. the original is supposed to be renamed to filename -> 2024-02-17 filename V.1 and then copied at the same time 2024-02-17 filename V.2

```
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ touch testfile1
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ./addversioninfo testfile1
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 21:45  ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 20:23  ../
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 clady clady 2645 Feb 21 20:23  addversioninfo*
```

Test case 2:
If there's a date but no version number, add version numbers.

```
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ touch "2024-01-01 testfile2"
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ./addversioninfo "2024-01-01 testfile2"
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 21:45  ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 20:23  ../
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-01-01 testfile2 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile2 V.2'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 clady clady 2645 Feb 21 20:23  addversioninfo*
```

Test case 3:
If there's not a date but a version number, keep the version number, but add the current date.

```
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ./addversioninfo "testfile3 V.9"
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 21:46  ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 20:23  ../
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-01-01 testfile2 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile2 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:46 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.10'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:46 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.9'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 clady clady 2645 Feb 21 20:23  addversioninfo*
```

test case 4:
subsequent iterations should increment the version number at the end.

```
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ./addversioninfo '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.10'
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 21:47  ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 20:23  ../
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-01-01 testfile2 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile2 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:47 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.10'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:47 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.11'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:46 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.9'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 clady clady 2645 Feb 21 20:23  addversioninfo*
```

test case 5
Preserve file extensions

```
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ touch testfile1.c
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ./addversioninfo testfile1.c
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 21:48  ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 20:23  ../
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-01-01 testfile2 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:48 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1.c'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:48 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2.c'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile2 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:47 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.10'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:47 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.11'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:46 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.9'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 clady clady 2645 Feb 21 20:23  addversioninfo*
```

test case 6
Increment version number with extension

```
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ touch  "2024-01-10 abc.md"
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ./addversioninfo  "2024-01-10 abc.md"
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 21:50  ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 clady clady 4096 Feb 21 20:23  ../
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-01-01 testfile2 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:50 '2024-01-10 abc V.1.md'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:50 '2024-02-21 abc V.2.md'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:48 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.1.c'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:48 '2024-02-21 testfile1 V.2.c'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:45 '2024-02-21 testfile2 V.2'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:47 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.10'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:47 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.11'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 21 21:46 '2024-02-21 testfile3 V.9'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 clady clady 2645 Feb 21 20:23  addversioninfo*
```

test case 7
Base file has a space in it:

```
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ touch "ABC 123 V.3"
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ../addversioninfo "ABC 123 V.3"
clady@clady01-PC:~/junkdir$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 clady clady 4096 Feb 29 08:15  ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 clady clady 4096 Feb 29 08:13  ../
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 29 08:15 '2024-02-29 ABC 123 V.3'
-rw-r--r--  1 clady clady    0 Feb 29 08:15 '2024-02-29 ABC 123 V.4'
```

If you like this solution, please up vote it and mark is as accepted.

Comment: I think it's almost correct, but the version numbers is coming after the file extension. This would screw up some things for me. How would I correct this? Thanks!!

Comment: Just so I am clear, I updated the script in the solution to handle file extensions.

Comment: Thanks! I've marked it as the solution, because it's almost perfect I just have one more case that's not quite working.
If I run the script on "2024-01-10 abc.md" it turns this (correctly) into "2024-01-10 abc V.1.md" but then the copy is called "2024-02-21 abc V.1.md" (i.e. the version of the copy gets the same number). Is this fixable? Thanks!!

Comment: Okay, at first there was an easy fix for your one test case, but then while testing it, I found other corner cases where I think it didn't do what you wanted, so I made some significant changes, but at the same time, I think it is pretty rock solid now.

Comment: I have another problem now. Don't know why I didn't realize this earlier, but if there's a space in the `basename` part of the filename this doesn't work right. Then it does change the date to the current one, but doesn't increment the version it just resets to V.1. How would I fix this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of back and forth with ChatGPT (I know...) I've *almost* got it but not quite.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
current_date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')

# Function to check if a file exists
file_exists() {
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        return 0  # File exists
    else
        return 1  # File does not exist
    fi
}

# Function to increment the version number
increment_version() {
    local version_number="$1"
    local incremented_version=$((version_number + 1))
    echo "$incremented_version"
}

# Check if the filename starts with a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD
case "$filename" in
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\ *V.[0-9]*.md)
        # Extract the version number from the filename
        version_number=$(echo "$filename" | grep -oP 'V\.\K\d+')

        # Increment the version number
        version_number=$(increment_version "$version_number")

        # Remove the old date from the filename
        filename_without_date="${filename:11}"

        # Modify the filename with the incremented version number
        new_filename="${current_date} ${filename_without_date%V.*}V.${version_number}"

        # Check if a file with the same version number exists
        while file_exists "$new_filename.md"; do
            echo "File '$new_filename' already exists."
            # Increment the version number
            version_number=$(increment_version "$version_number")
            # Modify the filename with the incremented version number
            new_filename="${current_date} ${filename_without_date%V.*}V.${version_number}"
        done

        echo "Creating new file with version $version_number."
        
        # Copy the original file to the new filename using rsync
        echo "Copying '$filename' to '$new_filename.md'."
        rsync -a --progress "./$filename" "./$new_filename.md"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "File copied successfully."
        else
            echo "Error: Failed to copy file."
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        # If the filename does not start with a date
        echo "Filename does not start with a date."
        # Rename the original file with today's date and the filename
        new_filename="${current_date} ${filename}"

        # Add a version number to the filename
        version_number=1
        new_filename_with_version="${new_filename%.*} V.${version_number}"

        # Check if a file with the same filename exists
        while file_exists "$new_filename_with_version.md"; do
            echo "File '$new_filename_with_version' already exists."
            # Increment the version number
            version_number=$(increment_version "$version_number")
            # Modify the filename with the incremented version number
            new_filename_with_version="${new_filename%.*} V.${version_number}"
        done

        echo "Creating new file with version $version_number."
        
        # Copy the original file to the new filename using rsync
        echo "Copying '$filename' to '$new_filename_with_version.md'."
        rsync -a --progress "./$filename" "./$new_filename_with_version.md"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "File copied successfully."
        else
            echo "Error: Failed to copy file."
        fi
        
        # Copy the original file to a new filename with "V.1" suffix
        original_filename_with_version="${current_date} ${filename%.*} V.${version_number}"
        echo "Copying '$filename' to '$original_filename_with_version.md'."
        rsync -a --progress "./$filename" "./$original_filename_with_version.md"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Original file copied successfully."
        else
            echo "Error: Failed to copy original file."
        fi
        
        # Rename the original file with "V.1" suffix
        echo "Renaming original file to '$original_filename_with_version.md'."
        mv "./$filename" "./$original_filename_with_version.md"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Original file renamed successfully."
        else
            echo "Error: Failed to rename original file."
        fi
        
        # Copy the original file to a new filename with "V.2" suffix
        new_version_number=2
        new_filename_with_version_2="${current_date} ${filename%.*} V.${new_version_number}"
        # Check if a file with the same filename exists
        while file_exists "$new_filename_with_version_2.md"; do
            echo "File '$new_filename_with_version_2' already exists."
            # Increment the version number
            new_version_number=$(increment_version "$new_version_number")
            # Modify the filename with the incremented version number
            new_filename_with_version_2="${current_date} ${filename%.*} V.${new_version_number}"
        done
        
        echo "Creating new file with version $new_version_number."
        
        # Copy the original file to the new filename with "V.2" suffix using rsync
        echo "Copying '$filename' to '$new_filename_with_version_2.md'."
        rsync -a --progress "./$filename" "./$new_filename_with_version_2.md"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "File copied successfully."
        else
            echo "Error: Failed to copy file."
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

My goal is to check the filename.
the original is supposed to be renamed to
filename -> 2024-02-17 filename V.1
and then copied at the same time
2024-02-17 filename V.2

subsequent iterations should increment the version number at the end.

If there's not a date but a version number, keep the version number, but add the current date.

If there's a date but no version number, add version numbers.

Any help appreciated!